# Changing mass file names?

Tags: rename, filenames

I have an issue about how to change orders of that sac files name. I mean I have this order but I need to change it to the second one and thes ecommands should be on the script. Additionally, this change must be done with using column numbers.

OLD

```
2007.084.00.22.50.8930_2007.084.01.26.10.1430.GE.ISP..BHZ.D.SAC
2007.084.00.22.51.2930_2007.084.01.26.54.8430.GE.ISP..BHN.D.SAC
2007.084.00.25.42.9430_2007.084.01.27.59.2430.GE.ISP..BHE.D.SAC
```

NEW

```
2007.084.01.26.10.1430_2007.084.00.22.50.8930.GE.ISP..BHZ.D.SAC
2007.084.01.26.54.8430_2007.084.00.22.51.2930.GE.ISP..BHN.D.SAC
2007.084.01.27.59.2430_2007.084.00.25.42.9430.GE.ISP..BHE.D.SAC
```

Let me write the code that I try to finish in this way (if the answers will be in that way, it will be more helpful for me) and I don't know how to continue to finish this process.

```
#!/bin/bash

for sacfile in *SAC
do

echo $sacfile
n2=`echo $sacfile | cut -c 24-45`
echo $n2

done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming they're fixed length filenames this should work.

```
#!/bin/bash

for sacfile in *SAC
do
    new_sacfile=${sacfile:23:22}_${sacfile:0:22}${sacfile:45}
    echo mv -v ${sacfile} ${new_sacfile}
done
```

We're using [bash's built in variable manipulation](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) to cut up the file name and rearrange it to our desire. When you're happy you can remove the echo in front of the `mv` statement

Comment: Thanks for your commend but I only get 

`mv -v 2007.084.00.22.50.8930_2007.084.01.26.10.1430.GE.ISP..BHZ.D.SAC 2007.084.01.26.10.1430_2007.084.00.22.50.8930.GE.ISP..BHZ.D.SAC
mv -v 2007.084.00.22.51.2930_2007.084.01.26.54.8430.GE.ISP..BHN.D.SAC 2007.084.01.26.54.8430_2007.084.00.22.51.2930.GE.ISP..BHN.D.SAC
mv -v 2007.084.00.25.42.9430_2007.084.01.27.59.2430.GE.ISP..BHE.D.SAC 2007.084.01.27.59.2430_2007.084.00.25.42.9430.GE.ISP..BHE.D.SAC`

on my terminal screen, so I couldn't get these files with new names ?

Comment: Well like I said in the post "When you're happy with the output you can remove the `echo` from in front of the `mv` statement"

Comment: oh, sorry mate I unnoticed that, it works great Thank you so much.

Comment: @kejinatsu not a problem, happy to help.